# How do I add grouping, programmatically?

Tags: 8, views

I've added a custom field to a view and want to display results as a grid grouped by this field. How do I set that "Grouping field Nr.1" option in my code? I tried the `hook_views_pre_build()` using the `$view->addHandler` but m not able to make it work. I guess the issue lies in the `$option` array and the `$type` parameter for `addHandler` method. Here is my code.

```
function utility_views_pre_view(ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args) {
  if ($view->id() == 'frontpage' && $display_id == 'page_1') {
    $options = array(
      'style' => array(
        'options' => array(
          'grouping' => array(
            'field_category',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    $view->addHandler("page_1", "grouping", "node__field_category", "field_category", $options);
  }
}
```

**Update**
When I use `$view->addHandler("page_1", "field", "node__field_category", "field_category", $options);` I get the a catgeory field added to each of the view items.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution. The grouping is not an Eventhandler in Drupal 8 but a Plugin (`Style Plugin`) specifically. Here is the code

```
function utility_views_pre_build(ViewExecutable $view) {
  $view->style_plugin->options['grouping'][0] = array('field' => 'field_category');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me in Drupal 8

```
function utility_views_pre_view(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args) {
    $view->getStyle()->options['grouping'][0]['field'] = 'field_category';
    }
```